# Questions on installing a bathroom exhaust fan

Tags: bathroom, ducts, exhaust-fan, exhaust-vent, product-recommendation

I am in the process of installing a new bathroom exhaust fan ([Panasonic FV-0511VKL2](https://na.panasonic.com/us/home-and-building-solutions/ventilation-indoor-air-quality/ventilation-fans/whispergreenr-select-fanlight-50-80-110-cfm)). I had a few questions (my apologies if they are trivial or obvious but its my first time doing something by myself).

1. Should I go with a 6" duct or 4"? Thinking 6" since its about a 6ft run to the wall
   plus the fact that 6" is more efficient than 4".
2. While the fan indicates it can do both 4" or 6" - it seems like the port itself is 4". Do I need to modify something on the fan port to make it 6"?
3. If I do go with 6" (I am planning on using this [insulated flexible duct](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Master-Flow-6-in-x-25-ft-Insulated-Flexible-Duct-R6-Silver-Jacket-F6IFD6X300/100396935)) would the receiving vent outlet also need to be 6" - I ask because I haven't found very many 6" vent kits - most are 4". Should I get a 4" vent and then tack on a adapter that increases it to 6" so the duct hose can connect to the cap snugly?
4. Lastly - most vents (beyond 4") don't explicitly say they can be used as a bathroom exhaust vent - they seem to be made for dryer vents? Are these vents made for dual purpose - dryer and bathroom exhaust?

Any recommendations on a vent kit would be much appreciated?

Thanks in advance for your time and advice.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You must post questions individually.

Comment: Are you venting through a wall or through the roof (preferred)? 4" should be fine. The fan installation instructions should have specs for the length/path of the venting between fan and outlet. You might want to leave a low spot in the ducting for condensate to collect so it doesn't flow back into your fan, and a damper just before the roof vent if it doesn't have one built in.

Comment: Hi @Armand planning to vent through the wall - our energy assessment company that was planning to do some blow-in insulation requested we vent through the wall and not the roof. My research was inconclusive on this front - there are just as many articles that advocate for venting thru the roof as there are for the wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Larger ducts are required for larger fans.  Typically in a residential bathroom you don't need a huge fan.  What's the CFM rating of your fan?   If it's very large, do you really need that?  If so, you should use the larger duct.   Look at the instructions and/or search for tables showing what to use.
2. If your joists run directly towards an outside wall, you are probably looking at 3 or 4 feet of straight duct with no bends.  That's a strong argument in favor of the smaller duct, not requiring adapters at both ends.
3. If your duct has to go along a joist then snake up into an attic, over some rafters, back down into an eave, then along a few feet, back down and then out .... (or whatever) .... then you'll need a bigger duct.   On the other hand, the *insulated* six-inch duct is 10 inches in overall diameter.  It's a pain to work with in tight spaces.   If this is your situation you should think hard about what you need from a fan and how to get it.
4. As for the exhaust vent, you can probably find a 6 inch one but they are less common and then you'll need a six inch hole in your wall.  Let's go back to "do you really need this?"

Note: you say 6 foot run.  You should locate the fan *away* from the bathroom door, which often means it can be *near* the outside wall, decreasing run length.   Air will flow in through the door and out through the fan.  If the fan is in the middle of the room or near the door, there will be dead air near the outside wall.  Consider putting the fan closer to the outside wall to increase the area of the room through which air will flow, and decrease the duct length.

Comment: HI @jay613 - my answers to your Qs. 
1. Its a variable 50-80-110 CFM fan. The tables for a 110CFM suggests 6" - hence the initial choice. 
2. Yes, my joists do run towards a wall. 

Based on all the answers/comments I will keep it simple and go with 4" duct.

It's a small bathroom - 7.5' x 5' - given it's size and the position of the shower, the duct will be 4' from the wall/window and 3.5' from the door. Is that a good spot or should I get even closer to the door?

Comment: I think in such a small bathroom it really doesn't matter, but *in theory* the fan should be far from the door and near to the exterior wall, that way it will draw air through the door, move air through the whole room, and eject it through a short duct.   Just think about air flow *through* the room.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it as simple as possible:

- 4"

Yes, 6" allows for greater flow. But 6' is not a very long distance and you have 4" on both the fan itself and most vent kits. So 4" will keep things simple.

- Non-insulated

Insulated ductwork is used to keep hot or cold air from changing temperature too much in transit (and wasting heat or cold to the attic, crawlspace, etc.). Bathroom exhaust can be relatively warm but for the short distance and short usage time, the amount of heat that will get into your attic space with uninsulated ductwork is relatively small. The other reason for a bathroom fan (arguably the much bigger reason) is to remove moisture, and for that insulation is irrelevant.

As to the general question of: *Could* I use dryer vents? Yes, you could. The reason why you typically see dryer vents larger than bathroom exhaust vents is simply the amount of air being pushed through.

Comment: Insulation reduces the amount of condensation in the duct for bathroom exhausts.

Comment: Manufacturers (at least some) recommend insulated ducts to improve noise control.  I used insulated for that reason, combined with the potential for condensation in the attic when pumping cooled house air through it in the summer.  But I stuck with 4 inch partly because getting the 6 inch insulated through various tight attic spaces would have been painful.

Comment: HI @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact - I am sold on the 4" duct but just to reduce the likelihood of mold on account of moisture (which is what prompted the installation of the fan - I will opt to use the insulated flex duct.

Answer (score 0):

6 feet is not a particularly long run. 4" smooth (rigid) duct externally insulated might flow as well as 6" flexible insulated duct. In any case 4" won't be a huge loss (even if you use flex), nor 6" a huge gain for such a short distance. As you've already seen, 4" parts are easier to find. Don't overcomplicate it.

Do bring the duct up and then slope it slightly down towards the wall exit so that condensation runs out the wall, not back into the room.

Comment: Hi @Ecnerwal - thanks for the suggestions to keep it simple and to angle the duct work towards the wall - will do.